# Hibernate and AspectJ field access

Tags: java, hibernate, aspectj

I have a question related to intercepting hibernate field accesses. I need to make some checks on fields before they are persisted by Hibernate.

I was thinking about using AspectJ and field access join points, but this does not work with Hibernate. Any other calls/accesses to the fields are well intercepted but not when accessed by hibernate.

So this works ok when using the getters, but this doesn't work if I use field access with hibernate.

I think this is due to the fact that Hibernate is using reflection.

Do you see any way I can intercept this?

I have something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

@Id
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

}
```

and a DAO method doing

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public Long createEmployee(Employee employee) {
    entityManager.persist(employee);
    return employee.getId();
}
```

Then I have an aspect like this

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Pointcut("get(* test.Employee.*)")
    public void executionGetField() {}  

@Around("executionGetField()")
public Object onGet(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    System.out.println("executionGetField " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    Object o = null;
    try {
        o = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        return o;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When looking at my traces I can see that any access to the fields are being intercepted by the aspect, except when the object is persisted by Hibernate in the createEmployee method. This is certainly because of the Reflection. So I am wondering how I can make it work with hibernate too.

Comment: Some self-consistent sample code reproducing your problem, optimally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) here or on GitHub, would help the community to better answer your question. StackOverflow is about code. ;-) This way I can just provide a very general answer.

Comment: Your aspect does nothing else than log the field access. This can hardly be your real use case. Why would you be interested in knowing that Hibernate accesses your fields? I surely has to in order to persist them. What do you *really* want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to modify the field value before it is accessed by hibernate

Comment: As I said, I am a Hibernate noob, have never used it. But a quick web search shows that there is the concept of [interceptors](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_interceptors.htm) in Hibernate. How about using one of those as a hook in order to finish up your properties before they are saved?

Comment: As I am using JPA I think I will use PrePersist as a listener instead.

Answer (score 0):

If `set()` / `get()` pointcuts do not work due to reflection - have you actually verified you assumption via Hibernate source code inspection or debugging? - you can only solve the problem indirectly by weaving your aspect code into the parts of Hibernate where field access is done. This can be done via binary weaving at compile time, creating an aspect-enhanced version of your Hibernate library, or dynamically during runtime via load-time weaving.

Not being a Hibernate user, I cannot say anything intelligent about how you should use that tool, but I strongly assume that there must be a better, more canonical way to achieve what you want than what I have just described. Please share some code and do not just describe what is not working, but what you want to achieve. I am pretty confident that some Hibernate geek will be able to provide you with a more elegant solution. As much as I love AspectJ, it is not the only way of solving *all* problems.

Comment: Thanks. I have added a simple code snippet. Hope this will help.